# Does firmware affect GPS accuracy?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gps

I am from Philippines, and using European firmware for my Samsung Galaxy S2. Does that affect the accuracy of my GPS? For example, my location is usually off (at the wrong location) when I use Foursquare. But sometimes, it's usually right in Google Maps.

Should I be using firmware for Philippines instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firmware definitely won't affect the quality of GPS reception (atleast in case of original ROMs, as homebrew ROMs might have some bugs - EVEN then it's either the fact that the GPS fix might take longer than usual or the GPS doesn't work at all. Not associated with accuracy.) What affects GPS reception is the quality of the signal. You tend to get a better and a faster GPS fix if you're in the open rather than in a closed building.

I've seen that Foursquare and Google Maps always point at the same location. (No brainer.)

Comment: For me, Google Maps has better accuracy than Foursquare. If I go to Foursquare, it's off. When I open Google Maps, it corrects itself. (Eventually, it becomes correct in Foursquare). Thanks for your input! :)